# Why is form returning null value for a checked radiobutton instead of true or false?

Tags: radio-button, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

I have a Boolean field in my model that I'm using an Editor template for in order to display the radio buttons for Yes and No.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Disruption)

@{
  Dictionary<string, object> yesAttrs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  Dictionary<string, object> noAttrs = new Dictionary<string, object>();

  yesAttrs.Add("id", ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("") + "Yes");
  noAttrs.Add("id", ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("") + "No");

  if (Model.HasValue && Model.Value)
  {
      yesAttrs.Add("checked", "checked");
  }
  else if (Model.HasValue && !Model.Value)
  {
      noAttrs.Add("checked", "checked");
  }
}

@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, "true", yesAttrs) 
<label for="@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(""))Yes">Yes</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, "false", noAttrs) 
<label for="@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(""))No">No</label>
```

Using the console viewer in developer tools on the browser I can see that when I check Yes the value is true and when I check No the value is false, yet when I click Submit the insert fails as the column cannot contain a NULL value. Why is the true or false value not being passed correctly in this case when the same code seems to work on other fields?

Comment: What is the the name of the property? - why are you not just using `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.YourPropertyName, "true")?

Comment: I read that it was better practice to use editor templates where possible so I took the code for the editor from an article

Comment: 20 lines of code that doesn't work vs 4 that do - I don't consider that best practice! What is the html that is being generated? Does it have `name="Disruption"`?

Comment: Changed to RadioButtonFor but still get the same error. HTML generated is: id="DisruptionYes" name="Disruption" value="true" and id="DisruptionNo" name="Disruption" value="false"

Comment: The html looks fine. What is the signature of the controller? Have you checked the `Request.Form` property when you post back?